# Upload image with a single button in html

Tags: javascript, html, upload

I'm a newbie in html/javascript and made two buttons that can upload image (choose file button and upload button).

However, I want to make it to just a single button and don't know how to combine those two button. I already searched on google, they said we can use `onchange` to combine submit button but I already have `onchange` function that can show image right away after choosing image file to iframe.

Here is my html code for `<form>`

```
 <form action="/upload", method="post", enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div style='height:0px; width:0px; overflow:hidden;'><input type="file" name="upFile" id="upFile" onchange="getCmaFileView(this, 'name').submit()" target="dropzone_1"/></div>
 </form>
```

Also, here is my script and button

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
  function getFile(){
    document.getElementById("upFile").click();
  }
</script>
...
    <li><a onclick="getFile()" style="cursor:pointer; color:#000000;">Choose File</a></li>
```

I tried with adding `.submit()` in onchange, but it didn't work.

Does anybody have an idea for this?

Please please help me out here!

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

```
function getCmaFileInfo(obj,stype) {
        var fileObj, pathHeader , pathMiddle, pathEnd, allFilename, fileName, extName;
        var file;
        var img, reader;
         // file = upload.files[0];
        upload = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        holder = document.getElementById('dropzone');
        reader = new FileReader();
        file = upload.files[0];
        var iupload, holder;

        reader.onload = function (event) {
                img = new Image();
                //console.log(event.target.result);
                img.src = event.target.result;
                img.width = document.getElementById("dropzone").clientWidth;
                img.height= window.innerHeight;
                // note: no onload required since we've got the dataurl...I think! :)
                holder.innerHTML = '';
                holder.appendChild(img);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function getCmaFileView(obj,stype) {
        getCmaFileInfo(obj,stype);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just **add one more function/code** in your getCmaFileView() - Which will just submit the form? Also it will be called after your image viewing part is done so that may solve your problem.

```
function getCmaFileView(obj,stype) {
        getCmaFileInfo(obj,stype);
        //form.submit() OR call_to_your_submit_function();
}
```

Comment: hm.. Thanks for the answer! Then should I put id in the form like `"myForm"` and then `document.getElementById("myForm").submit();`?

Comment: I'm not sure about the name or ID of the form, but yes try in your way.

Comment: Hm... It doesn't work... I don't know why.. after submit it shows previous image again...

Comment: oh man it works! :) Thanks! :) the problem was in Node.js! Thanks once again and hope you have a great day!

Comment: Have you written any code for form submit? Check the action URL and the code please, print your globals - POST and FILES to test it out.

Comment: Glad it worked ... Also for more small queries like this ... poke here.

Comment: Thanks! I also have a quick question, does tooltip can be clickable? I made a tooltip for each block and want it to be clickable and go to another link

Comment: Is there any links that I can look over? :)

Comment: M not sure ... do you want this ... Just add your tool tip text or icon inside <a target="_blank"></a> tag and you will be able to open the link.